# Ruby on Rails Custom Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a class in Ruby which exists in my **config/com/meow** location. After creating my class, I set my application.rb **config.autoload_paths** to the following:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/com/meow/)
```

When doing this, I received an error which stated uninitialized constant.

Thinking that I perhaps loaded the path wrong, I changed the path to the following:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/com/meow/"]
```

After doing this, I still received the same error, 'uninitialized constant'.

My goal is to reference a public method which exists in my custom Ruby class. I want to reference this method from the `ApplicationController`.

Inside my `ApplicationController`, I have a reference to the class and the method as defined by [class].[method]

What do I need to be doing to get around this error and in order to reference the methods contained within my class from my `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just a bit confused about what `config.root` will be. `config.root` is the root directory of your application, that's where the usual `app/`, `config/`, `db/`, ... directories are. So, if you want to add `config/com/meow` to the auto-load paths then you'd want:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/com/meow)
```

I'd probably just throw your custom classes in `lib/` though, then they'd be in a standard location where people would normally look and you wouldn't have to worry about customizing the auto-load paths.

Comment: Thanks. Both options worked. I opted to follow convention and your recommendation by moving my classes to the lib folder. Appreciate it.